# Access owning object from member variable

Tags: php

A code snippet is worth a thousand words:

```
class Foo {
  private $bar;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->bar = new Bar(); 
}

class Bar {
  public function getFoo() {
    // ???
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get a reference to the owning object instance (instance of `Foo`) inside a member variable class, without explicitly *passing the reference* to the member variable or using *reflection*?

Comment: No, there is no clean way. Technically, you could do `$this->bar = new Bar($this);` but it is terrible idea on multiple levels (one of those is "having `new` in a constructor").

Comment: `$baz = $this->bar` - now what!? There's no such thing as an "owning object".

Comment: @deceze that is why is created hermetization, to not allow usecase like that.

For what reason you need that? This will be bad practice. If you want access to that data, you simply need `protected function getBar(): Bar` that will return value of $bar.

Comment: @tereško Yes, I agree it's a bad idea, that's what I meant by "without explicitly passing the reference". I was hoping for a language construct or more elegant solution. In Java, for example, inner classes can access parent class instance

Comment: @timiTao accessing `$bar` from `$foo` is not an issue; it's the other way around ;) The reason is, specifically, accessing owning document from embedded documents in Doctrine ODM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection doesn't help here.

The request doesn't make sense anyway. Assuming you have a working implementation for `Bar::getFoo()`. What should it return in the following situations?

1. A `Bar` object is created outside any `Foo` object:

   ```
   $bar = new Bar();
   $bar->getFoo();           // ??
   ```
2. A `Bar` object is created by a `Foo` object and it is linked to another `Foo` object:

   ```
    $foo1 = new Foo();
    $foo2 = new Foo();
    $foo2->copyBar($foo1);

    class Foo {
        // ...
        public function copyBar(Foo $foo) { $this->bar = $foo->bar; }
    }
   ```

The only correct solution to your problem is to pass the `Foo` object to the constructor of the `Bar` object and let the `Bar` object keep the back reference to the `Foo` object that created (and owns) it:

```
class Foo {
    private $bar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = new Bar($this); 
    }
}

class Bar {
    private $foo;

    public function __construct(Foo $foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function getFoo() {
        return $this->foo;          // of course
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is the solution I'm using so far, but I was wondering whether it is possible to do this *without explicitly passing the reference*. Besides being manual labour, it didnt make sense to me that the owning object could so easily access it's member variable objects (`$foo->bar`) but there was not a language construct for the other way around

Comment: Doing this explicitly is better, it is more readable and "type safe" (as much as php can be type safed...)